# Managing user profile for code

Tags: vb.net, profiling, user-profile

I'm working on a project on VB.NET that requires multiple clients to access the software simultaneously. However these clients will be having different levels of authority on the software such as some will be Admins, some will be Managers, some will be Users.

As pictured, the Users will have only certain features of the software available to them and Admins have full control on the software.

I will be asking the clients to identify themselves when they start the software, maybe through a Username and Password. Once identified, the forms application should show only relevant forms and controls to them.

How do I develop my code so that I can incorporate User profiling? Are there any industry-standard ways of going about with this?

Comment: This is a small project in itself and therefore not the right question for StackOverflow. You should try to get an experienced developer to solve this problem for you

Comment: Ummm...so does that mean StackOverflow only solves big project problems???
I don't have any experienced developers around me. And I'm learning things alone. So it would've been great if you could've helped if you knew a solution...

Comment: You misunderstood me. The small project is too complex for a simple answer. Wade73's answer shows that. You yourself wrote «quite complex to understand».

Comment: Oh like that...well that's true...
Well his answer was quite up to the mark. I'm just trying to work around that. He gave me a good direction to research on...

Answer (score 0):

I would look into role-based security as a good starting point.  Here is an article I found that gives an example of doing this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480723.aspx  It is a bit outdated (2006), but I think the concepts should be current.

HTH

Wade

Comment: That helps quite a bit. That article targets quite exactly my problem domain. However, its quite complex to understand it. I shall read it a couple of times more.
Thanks :)

Comment: No problem and I will help where I can, if you have any other questions.

Comment: hmmm...its not gonna help at a granular level as in in buttons, will it?
Say, If I add a delete button which all Admins can use at all times to delete records. But Users can use it only if they've created that record. Otherwise, they should not be able to use it. That means a User cannot delete other people records.

So basically I would want the delete button to be visible to the user only when it satisfies this condition. Otherwise, no. Will granular role-based security be an answer to this?

Comment: Well, you would need to have the granularity set to that specific record, so user1 would be in the owner role for that particular record.  Not sure how difficult that would be.

Comment: Hey Wade, I was going again through that link you gave above.
I understood till point 3 but not 4 and 5. Are points 4 and 5 specific to Azman or is it applicable to any project?
How can I map what is there in that article to my project?

Comment: I am going to say that the code in the article is specific to Azman. Given that you need to have roles based on the record, unlike the article, I would suggest that you will need to look at another software pattern.  For now I would suggest going to MSDN and reading up on role-based security.